# UPDATE from SELECT complains about more that one value returned

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have this data structure:

```
request
=======
building_id
lot_code

building
========
building_id
lot_id

lot
===
lot_id
lot_code
```

The `request` table is missing the value for the `building_id` column and I want to fill it in from the other tables. So I've tried this:

```
UPDATE request
SET building_id = (
    SELECT bu.building_id
    FROM building bu
    INNER JOIN lot lo ON bu.lot_id=lo.lot_id
    WHERE lo.lot_code = request.lot_code
);
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

Is it due to wrong syntax? The data model allows more than one building per lot but actual data doesn't contain such cases so there should be at most one `building_id` per `lot_code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you mean

```
UPDATE request
SET building_id = bu.building_id
FROM building bu
    INNER JOIN lot lo ON bu.lot_id=lo.lot_id
WHERE lo.lot_code = request.lot_code
```

Answer (score 0):

use top 1 in your query as in example below.

```
UPDATE request
SET building_id = (
    SELECT top 1 bu.building_id
    FROM building bu
    INNER JOIN lot lo ON bu.lot_id=lo.lot_id
    WHERE lo.lot_code = request.lot_code
);
```